# How do I detect a failing command in popen?

Tags: c, pipe, posix

I'm trying to figure out how to detect when a command invoked by *popen* fails. In the program `test.c` below, *popen* returns non-null although the command fails. Any clues?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int status;

    fp = popen("foo", "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        puts("command successful");
        status = pclose(fp);
        if (status < 0) {
            perror(NULL);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else {
        perror(NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./test
command successful
sh: 1: foo: not found
```

Comment: As I understand the man page, `pclose` should return the exit code. You are testing for `<0` here, which would be true if `pclose` itself fails. Testing for `>0` would then test if the called program failed (had exit code >0).

Comment: "The pclose() function waits for the associated process to terminate and returns the exit status of the command as returned by wait4." Do you have the binary 'foo' from where you are running this program?

Comment: @KarstenKoop Thanks! If you turn you comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pclose), `pclose` should return the exit code. You are testing for <0 here, which would be true if `pclose` itself fails. Testing for >0 would then test if the called program failed (had exit code >0).

Man page of `pclose`:

> The pclose() function waits for the associated process to terminate and returns the exit status of the command as returned by wait4.

and

> The pclose() function returns -1 if wait4 returns an error, or some other error is detected.